# ArcGIS mosaic to new raster colour difference

Tags: raster, arcmap, sentinel-2, image-mosaic

I am trying to merge two rasters from a Sentinel-2 scene in ArcMap 10.5. They are next to each other geographically and were taken moments apart on the same day. Prior to this issue I have used the composite bands tool for each to add together the separate sentinel bands. When I display them without mosaicking, there is a difference in their colours (presumably from one image containing a few clouds resulting in a different stretched histogram). I assumed this would right itself when the two images were merged into one raster. However, I have tried using the 'mosaic to new raster' tool, as well as adding the rasters to a new mosaic dataset, and the colours are still different between the two halves of the image. I've attached an image of the output I got from adding them to a new mosaic dataset.

Is there any way I can rectify this and make them look seamless? I am worried that when I run vegetation indices the outputs will be inaccurate.

[image: Tool output]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, it turned out I had downloaded one half of the composite as a Sentinel-2 MSI level-1C image and the other half as level-2A. In addition to meaning the upper half lacked a band 10, they looked different when stitched together despite being from the same satellite. To rectify I had to go back to the Copernicus open access hub and download the level-1C images and start over which took some time, but it then looked seamless when I had resampled and stitched!